# Laravel relationship is not loading in Resource?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to load the relation of order with customer but it is returning `null` in the postman
[image]

***Customer Model***

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Customer extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
     use Notifiable;


    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone_number',
        'postal_code',
        'email',
        'preferred_method_to_contact',
        'password',
        'address',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        $name = $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
        return $name;
    }

    public function orders()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

***Order Model***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'phone_number',
            'post_code',
            'address',
            'alternative_address',
            'property_type',
            'property_type_other',
            'contract_type',
            'contract_type_other',
            'no_of_bedrooms',
            'no_of_bathrooms',
            'customer_id',
            'best_day',
            'best_time',
            'type_of_cleaning',
        ];


    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

***Order Resource***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class OrderResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        /*return parent::toArray($request);*/
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'phone_number' => $this->phone_number,
            'post_code' => $this->post_code,
            'address' => $this->address,
            'alternative_address' => $this->alternative_address,
            'property_type' => $this->property_type,
            'property_type_other' => $this->property_type_other,
            'contract_type' => $this->contract_type,
            'contract_type_other' => $this->contract_type_other,
            'no_of_bedrooms' => $this->no_of_bedrooms,
            'phone_number' => $this->phone_number,
            'no_of_bathrooms' => $this->no_of_bathrooms,
            'customer' => new CustomerResource($this->whenLoaded('customers')),
        ];
    }
}
```

***Customer Resource***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CustomerResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
     public function toArray($request)
    {
        /*return parent::toArray($request);*/
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is the function in `OrderController` which is responsible for sending the JSON response

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:50'],
            'phone_number' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'post_code' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:300'],
            'alternative_address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:300'],
            'property_type' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'contract_type' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'no_of_bedrooms' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'type_of_cleaning' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'best_day' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'best_day' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        // $customer = Customer::findOrFail($request->customer_id);
        $order = Order::create($request->all());
        // $order = Order::create();
        $order->load(array('customers'));

        return new OrderResource($order);
    }
```

I want the customer details to be loaded along with the order.

Comment: I think you have forgotten to import CustomerResource resource in your OrderResource  file.

Comment: Yes.. I didn't.

Comment: Then add it, and check if you are getting the relationhsip or not.

Comment: No change. Returns `null`

Comment: I got the relationship finally. Thankyou so much for your response

Comment: how about this `'customer' => CustomerResource::find($this->customr_id),` ?

Comment: @Vipertecpro It was relationship issue as I have updated my answer

Comment: Okay that's great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to fix that problem. Actually the `ManyToOne` relationship function was not recognizing the `customers`. The `customers` function targets the `many-to-one` so it should be singular instead of plural according to the standards of laravel.

```
public function customer()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

Similarly in the `OrderController`

```
$order->load(array('customer')); // <- make it singular as well
```

In the `OrderResource`

```
'customer' => new CustomerResource($this->whenLoaded('customer')), // <- make it singular
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't fix it _quickly_ but _sustainably_ by renaming the relation. Bad naming of methods and variables is very high on the list of problematic mistakes when it comes to maintainability. Think about reading this code in three years again while looking for a bug. When the method is in plural form, you might overlook something because you think that it returns something different than it really does. For example `foreach($order->customers as $customer) { ... }` - you won't spot the mistake very fast...

Comment: @Namoshek I have already updated it on my side but for the future reference and to help others I have updated my answer as well.